# What does 'XXXXXX' mean as the second argument to TO_NUMBER? Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER fund_BIU   
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON fund  
FOR EACH ROW   
BEGIN
IF INSERTING AND :new.fundid IS NULL THEN   
    :new.fundid := TO_NUMBER(SYS_GUID(), 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');   
    END IF;   
END;
/
```

I'm interested the `IF` statement. What does it mean 
`:new.fundid := to_number(sys_guid(),'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');`. To be precise `sys_guid(), 'xxxxxxxx'` part.

TY

Comment: Have you tried Google? Searching for `oracle to_number` yields [this result](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions191.htm). Now try `oracle sys_guid`.

Comment: Well i tried google but the thing is i wanna know what it means here. I know that it is a if statement but i`m not sure what it means in this case. TY

Answer (score 3):

Think of the number 33. Focus on what that means - it's a number, it does not have digits. It can be represented as 3 * 10 + 3 * 1 which is why it has two digits in base 10, both digits equal to 3. But you could also represent it as 33.00. The strings '33' and '33.00' are clearly different (one has two characters, the other has five); but if you want to think of them as representing numbers, they represent the same number - the integer 33. Similarly, +33 and +33.00 represent the same number.

If you input a string like '33' or '+33.00' but you want to get out a number, then you use the function `TO_NUMBER()`. For example: '+33.00' is a string, but `TO_NUMBER('+33.00')` is a number, the number 33.

`TO_NUMBER()` allows you to give a format model, so that Oracle understands how to interpret the string it receives as input.

For example, if you input the string '1101' - is that the number one thousand one hundred one, or is it the number 13, given in binary representation?

Similarly, the number 33 has the string representation '21' in hexadecimal ("in HEX"). `TO_NUMBER('21')` will output the number 21; but you can tell Oracle that you meant a hexadecimal number, by providing the format model 'XX'. There are two X for two digits, and X is often used to mean "hex". So `TO_NUMBER('21', 'XX')` will output the number 33, not the number 21.

`SYS_GUID()` outputs the hexadecimal representation of a very large number. The output is a string. Applying `TO_NUMBER()` to it, with a format model that indicates it should be interpreted as a hex number, will convert it to an actual number (instead of a string of hex digits).

Answer (score 1):

What `SYS_GUID()` does is generate a unique 16 byte identifier or key. When applying the `TO_NUMBER()` function, you are getting the 32 number representation of that key. It is basically a way of generating unique numbers in Oracle.

See `SYS_GUID()` in Oracle documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/functions153.htm

Comment: It is just a unique sequence for each row in a table. Another explanation here might be useful: http://psoug.org/definition/SYS_GUID.htm

Comment: For further explanation, what this `IF` statement is doing is the following: if the `:new.fundid` (which I'm guessing is the primary key in the `fund` table) is null, assign a unique value to it to serve as the primary key. This unique value is generated by `SYS_GUID()`, and simply turned into a 32-digit number using the `TO_NUMBER()` function.